# How to rewrite coordinator.xml in hadoop?

Tags: xml, hadoop, oozie-coordinator

The situation is next: **the coordinator should be triggered only if in *"/user/task"* directory the file *"_SUCCESS"* exists**, but when you're creating a coordinator there's only one option "*how often?*", so I need to rewrite *coordinator.xml* somehow. Can anybody help me with this? The content of *coordinator.xml* is next:

```
     <coordinator-app name="My_Coordinator"
  frequency="0 0 * * *"
  start="${start_date}" end="${end_date}" timezone="America/Los_Angeles"
  xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2"
  >
  <controls>
    <execution>FIFO</execution>
  </controls>
  <action>
    <workflow>
      <app-path>${wf_application_path}</app-path>
      <configuration>
        <property>
          <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
          <value>True</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>start_date</name>
          <value>2015-11-09T22:46Z</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>end_date</name>
          <value>2015-11-16T22:46Z</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
   </workflow>
  </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Comment: How many times do you suppose the coordinator to run? Only once?

Comment: for the beginning it will be enough to run only once))

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a dataset in the coordinator config:

```
<datasets>
    <dataset name="some-name" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="..." timezone="...">
        <uri-template>
            ...
        </uri-template>
    </dataset>
</datasets>
```

Workflow will be run daily.

See [more](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a5.1._Synchronous_Datasets) about datasets.

Comment: yeah, but I need it to run only if "_SUCCESS" file exists in /user/task/ directory

Comment: It will work as you expect. From docs: "done-flag: The done file for the data set. If done-flag is not specified, then Oozie configures Hadoop to create a _SUCCESS file in the output directory."

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved not by changing *xml* file, but simply using the following *bash script*:

```
if ! hadoop fs -test -e /user/task/_SUCCESS; then
echo file not found
exit 1
fi
echo file found
exit 0
```